# rspec unit testing a method which has a infinite loop

Tags: unit-testing, rspec

I have a method like this

```
class SomeClass
  def self.test_method
    while(true)
      make_heavy_lifting
      sleep(60*60)
    end
  end
end
```

How do i write test for this method.

one solution i thought of is stubbing sleep method and it worked but i am not able to stub the while keyword. please suggest best practices for unit testing a method which has infinite loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you can move everything inside the while except the sleep to another method, then you write specs only for that method, I don't think you really need to test that your method has a while loop and a sleep (you don't need to test EVERY line of your code :P) but if you want to do that check this question, it has some things you can try [What is the best practice when it comes to testing "infinite loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717813/what-is-the-best-practice-when-it-comes-to-testing-infinite-loops)

Comment: Agreed. but i was hoping is there any way to stub the while(true) keyword. if its not then i have to separate the logic out of it.

Answer (score 5):

To test this I stub `:loop` and use that instead of `while(true)`:

class:

```
class SomeClass
  def self.test_method
    loop do
      make_heavy_lifting
      sleep(60*60)
    end
  end
end
```

spec:

```
describe SomeClass do
  describe '#test_method' do
    expect(SomeClass).to receive(:loop).and_yield
    expect(SomeClass).to receive(:make_heavy_lifting)
    expect(SomeClass).to receive(:sleep).with(60*60)
end
```

this way it will only iterate through it once.

EDIT:
it seems this was also suggested in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33348498/2171041)